# Last ChartObject in Collection scaling the wrong chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that converts some old charts in Excel to a new format. Running the `ConvertAllChartsInSheet` method below seems to work as required, until it gets to the last chart in the sheet. On the last one, it changes the font and font size of the chart correctly. However, it scales the width and height of the chart that comes before it in the loop, despite using the same ChartObject. What could cause this?

```
Sub ConvertSingleChart(ByRef cht As ChartObject)

    cht.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    cht.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

    ' Change the font and label size
    With cht.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .Name = FontName
        .Size = FontSize
    End With

    ' Change the font and font size of the labels
    ConvertLabelsInChart cht

End Sub

Sub ConvertAllChartsInSheet(ByRef actSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim cht As ChartObject

    For Each cht In actSheet.ChartObjects
        ConvertSingleChart cht
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was because the last chart and the chart before both had the same name within the worksheet. After changing the names so they're all distinct, the problem was solved.

You can change the name of a chart by selecting it and setting a new value in the top left of Excel, in the field next to the formula field. See below:

[image]